# Excel: need to transpose one field of multiple values while duplicating the remaining fields

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that has column E that requires values split (comma separated values currently) and transposed to multiple rows. Columns C, D, F-S need copied down. Example:
Columns

```
+-----+-------+------------------+-------+--------+--------+----------+
|  C  |   D   |        E         |   F   |   G    |   H    | ... S    |
+-----+-------+------------------+-------+--------+--------+----------+
| 20  |  hey  |  one, two, three |  xyz  |  unit  |  right | ... end  |
+-----+-------+------------------+-------+--------+--------+----------+
```

I need it to look like:

```
+-----+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| C   |   D   |   E    |   F   |    G   |    H   |  ... S  |
+-----+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| 20  |  hey  |  one   |  xyz  |  unit  |  right | ... end |
| 20  |  hey  |  two   |  xyz  |  unit  |  right | ... end |
| 20  |  hey  |  three |  xyz  |  unit  |  right | ... end |
+-----+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
```

any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

**This Code should help you...**

```
Sub GetOutput()

    Dim rndData                 As Range
    Dim rngOutCell              As Range
    Dim MainIindex              As Integer '<< Column index Needs to be split
    Dim AllData                 As Variant  '<< Data Range
    Dim InnerData               As Variant '<< Split Data
    Dim intRecordCounter        As Integer

    MainIindex = 3
    lngDataRow = 0

    Set rndData = Sheet1.Range("E1").CurrentRegion
    Set rngOutCell = Sheet1.Range("O1")

    For intRecordCounter = 1 To rndData.Rows.Count

        AllData = rndData.Rows(intRecordCounter).Value
        InnerData = Split(rndData.Rows(intRecordCounter).Cells(MainIindex).Value, ",")

        Set rngOutCell = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, rngOutCell.Column).End(xlUp)
        If rngOutCell <> vbNullString Then
            Set rngOutCell = rngOutCell.Offset(1)
        End If

        Set rngOutCell = rngOutCell.Resize(UBound(InnerData) + 1, UBound(AllData, 2))
        rngOutCell.Value = AllData
        rngOutCell.Offset(, MainIindex - 1).Resize(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(InnerData)

    Next intRecordCounter

ClearMemory:
    MainIindex = Empty
    If IsArray(AllData) Then Erase AllData
    If IsArray(InnerData) Then Erase InnerData
    intRecordCounter = Empty
    Set rndData = Nothing
    Set rngOutCell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, I tried this code and I received an error: Run-Time error 13: Type Mismatch; I checked debug and the line highlighted was  Set rngOutCell = rngOutCell.Resize(UBound(InnerData) + 1, UBound(AllData, 2))

Comment: have you changed the 'rndData'="C1"(wherever you data starts from

Comment: I changed the code to Set rndData=Sheet1.Range("C1").CurrentRegion

Comment: I am still receiving the Run-Time 13 error on the same line.

Comment: this code is perfectly working here... and chk ur mail